# Is there a way to add tooltip to text in a Discord bot message?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

It's the first time I'm writing a Discord bot, decided to go with the Discord.js module. One of my goals involved adding tooltips to certain words in a sentence so that the user can mouseover the word and get additional information.

The only idea I had after searching for an hour was using an embed message and using markdown to title a fake hyperlink. For exemple, if I wanted the word "tomato" to hint "Is a fruit" I'd write it as [tomato](javascript:; "Is a fruit").

This wouldn't have been too elegant but it would have worked, but it seems that setting the href to javascript:; or # is blocked. So using this method I'd be forced to provide a valid href which makes the hyperlink clickable.

I couldn't find anyone asking for this or any other leads on achieving this, is there another way to get tooltips in embed discord messages or is this an impossible endeavor?

Comment: Seems impossible. I've used discord and discord.js for a while and I've never seen any tooltip functionality either in discord itself or in the library. It might even pose some sort of security risk if javascript would be able to be put into links so I doubt it would be feasible.

Comment: Unfortunately, that is not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am a JDA Developer of a bot, but these things are the same!

It is impossible because discord on itself hasn´t even a tooltip option.

But you can make a link with these information's what you want to tooltip
the user, it is a little complicated but it would be a thing.

I hope it clarified your question.

Greetings
Just4Gamer